# Add event listener to element in React from external script

Tags: javascript, jquery, reactjs

I am working on a React app, but I can't change the actual React code. The only thing I can do: I can add an external script to the footer of page. The script I want to insert into the app is the following:

```js
$('input').keyup(function(event) {

  // skip for arrow keys
  if(event.which >= 37 && event.which <= 40) return;

  // format number
  $(this).val(function(index, value) {
   return value
          .replace(/\D/g, "")
          .replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, ",");
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p>Imagine a big react app with some input fields and the above script loaded in the footer using a script tag.</p> 
<input  />
```

It adds decimal separators to all input elements. I've taken it from https://codepen.io/kdivya/pen/oxVeWz. However, it doesn't work that way, because when the script is loaded, the DOM hasn't been constructed yet. Thus, according to the dev tools, the event listener isn't added to the input elements.

I researched a lot, but all related answers use some React lifecycle stuff, but afaik I can't utilize that from an external script. I also tried adding the event listener within $(document).ready(...), but it didn't work either. I'm open to all ideas (with or without JQuery, it can also use React I just don't know how to get into React structures from "outside").

Comment: "I am working on a React app, but I can't change the actual React code. The only thing I can do: I can add an external script to the footer of page." Why can't you change the React code? If you're doing this work for your employer, it sounds like your employer isn't giving you the tools to do the job.

Answer (score 0):

The main issue is that event *if* you bound event handlers to the input elements, you have no idea when React will rerender, creating new input elements that don't have your event handlers bound to them.  What I would do is use jQuery [event delegation](https://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/) to bind to the `body`, but only listen for events originating from `input` elements:

```js
$('body').on('keyup', 'input', function(event) {

  // skip for arrow keys
  if(event.which >= 37 && event.which <= 40) return;

  // format number
  $(this).val(function(index, value) {
   return value
          .replace(/\D/g, "")
          .replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, ",");
  });
});


// Example class component
class Thingy extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <input />
    );
  }
}

// Render it
ReactDOM.render(
  <Thingy />,
  document.getElementById("root")
);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>

<div id="root"/>
```

But, you may need to manually trigger the `change` event or something, so that React will "know" that you changed the input's value.

Something like:

```
$('body').on('keyup', 'input', function(event) {
    // ...
    $(this).trigger('change');
});
```

Comment: The event listener is now added, but whenever it changes the value, React will empty the field. So it basically conflicts with React's own state management. Any idea on how to resolve that?